# keep rows and the previous one which are not equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of dataframe :

```
d = {1 : [False,False,False,False,True],2:[False,True,True,True,False],3 :[True,False,False,False,True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df :
       1      2      3
0  False  False   True
1  False   True  False
2  False   True  False
3  False   True  False
4   True  False   True
```

My goal is to keep rows n+1 and n where rows n+1 and n are differents. In the example df, the result would be :

```
df_result :
       1      2      3 
0  False  False   True
1  False   True  False
3  False   True  False
4   True  False   True
```

I have already tried this line `df_result = df.neq(df.shift())` and kept only rows where there is a least one true but it doesn't get the row 3

Any idea how i can have the expected result ?

Thanks !

Comment: because this is a sample of the real dataframe which is much bigger and I don't know what it looks like

Comment: the column names are completely independent from rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need compare bot not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) shifting by `1` and by `-1`, get at least one match by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and chain with `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df_result = df[df.ne(df.shift()).any(axis=1) | df.ne(df.shift(-1)).any(axis=1)]
print (df_result)
       1      2      3
0  False  False   True
1  False   True  False
3  False   True  False
4   True  False   True
```

Another similar idea:

```
df_result = df[(df.ne(df.shift()) | df.ne(df.shift(-1))).any(axis=1)]
```